# Cannot connect vertices

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to create an edge between vertices. But when i press F it grabs them like I'm pressing G. Any help would be appreciated
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can not connect verts in different mesh objects. If you edit multiple objects at the same time you have to count with this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to join vertices from different objects. In order to bridge those vertices, you will have to join the objects together by going into object mode and selecting both objects and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.